# Eclipse takes forever while starting debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ide

I have created a new web project using java 1.8, Maven,Spring and Tomcat server. I am trying to debug my application through eclipse. But eclipse is taking forever. It is stuck at "Setting classpath containers".

Has anyone faced this issue and solved it? I am not able to find a solution anywhere else.

Comment: Does your debug session start eventually?

Comment: That's the issue! It gets stuck, and we don't know for how much time we should wait for it to "set classpath containers"

Comment: It should start instantly.  The message may not be indicative of the actual problem.  My guess would be that you perhaps have configured how Eclipse should use Tomcat incorrectly.  Please add exact details on how you got this far.